# SEO friendly URL with 2 get variables from dropdown select

Tags: javascript, php, forms, .htaccess, get

I have a form with 2 `dropdown select boxes` and a `submit button.`

`Dropdown 1` is country from, `dropdown 2` is country to. Data is filled from `MySQL database`

After submit it's being send to `compare.php` so the `url` becomes. `domain.com/compare.php?from=canada&to=usa`

I want this to become a SEO friendly URL like.

```
domain.com/travel-from-canada-to-usa.html
```

And keep the Get values so they can be used in the `compare.php` content.

I already have a rewrite so.

```
domain.com/travel-from-canada-to-usa.html will use domain.com/compare.php?from=canada&to=usa
```

Also set canonical on `domain.com/compare.php?from=canada&to=usa  to domain.com/travel-from-canada-to-usa.html`

But how to fix it with the form situation. Any help is welcome.

.htaccess at the moment is this

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^travel-from-([^-]*)-to-([^-]*)\.html$ /testmax/compare.php?from=$1&to=$2 [L]
```

Content is being generated dynamicly. So thats why it's important GET values are being send

Comment: You need to attempt something in htaccess, if you've tried something please post it.

Comment: I have this. But it's more for the other way around.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^travel-from-([^-]*)-to-([^-]*)\.html$ /testmax/compare.php?from=$1&to=$2 [L]

Content is being generated dynamicly. So thats why it's important GET values are being send

Comment: Put it in the question mate so it's clearer :)

Comment: Submit your html form using `POST` method.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the following solution a bit:

[Two drop down lists form to get one url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284699/two-drop-down-lists-form-to-get-one-url)

With this and my orginal rewrite it works.